# K&R mallocに参照の局所性によるメリットはありますか？

Tags: c++, linux, c, unix, operating-system

私はコンピュータについて勉強中で、mallocについて以下のスライドと動画を見ていました。
https://www.slideshare.net/kosaki55tea/glibc-malloc (スライド55ページ)
https://youtu.be/0-vWT-t0UHg?t=2758

ここでは、以下のように述べています。（K&R mallocでは、たった今freeしたアドレスを、次のmalloc時のためのfree-list舐めの開始アドレスに設定することについて）

> - メモリーに一番アクセスする確率が高いのは malloc 直後と free 直前である
> - free されたばかりのメモリはキャッシュに載ってる確率が高い
> - そこから優先してメモリ確保することは malloc 直後のアクセスでキャッシュミスしなくなるということ

これは本当ですか？

freeされたばかりの領域のデータがキャッシュに乗っていたところで、次のmalloc直後のアクセスは書き込みであり読み込みでは無いと思われるので、利用されないのではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 仮想記憶をサポートしたOSの場合、確保したいメモリーが必ずしも実メモリー上あるとは限りません。実メモリがない場合は、不必要なメモリーを破棄、またはストレージに退避することになると思います。キャッシュされたメモリーがあれば、それをすぐ使用できるので、上記の処理が発生しません。このようなことではないかと思います。

Comment: それは、書き込み時に、書き込み領域がスワップアウトされていた場合に、スワップインするまで処理をブロックする可能性があるということですか？ライトバックであってもそうなりますか？

Comment: 例えば、実メモリーに空きがない場合は、確保したいメモリーのスワップインだけで無く、不必要なメモリーのスワップアウトも発生しますよね。freeしたメモリーは不必要なため、破棄対象になると思いますが、それを破棄せず残しておくことにより、mallocですぐに使えるメモリーが確保で来ることになるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: @misaki ご自身で削除された回答が最も正しいと思います。差し支えなかったら削除の取り消しを行ってください。

Comment: @sayuri ありがとうございます。取り消ししました。しかし、削除した回答も見ることができるんですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

書き込みの際には、該当キャッシュラインに対するRFO（Read For Ownership）と呼ばれるリード操作が生じるためです。

MESIプロトコル（キャッシュコヒーレントプロトコル）では、自身のキャッシュが最新のデータである状態（Modified状態とExclusive状態）にするために、自身以外のキャッシュに対して当該キャッシュラインの無効化ブロードキャストを行います。当該キャッシュライン全体を無効化するため、書き込み部以外の周辺データも保持する必要があり、そのための読み込みです。

もっと簡単に言うと、書き込みもキャッシュラインに合わせて行うため、書き込み部周辺のデータを一度リードする必要があるということです。

Answer (score 1):

リンク先の記事を書いた人に `キャッシュ` というのは `CPU の 2次キャッシュ` だという前提で書いてみます。

> freeされたばかりの領域のデータがキャッシュに乗っていたところで、次のmalloc直後のアクセスは書き込みであり読み込みでは無いと思われるので、利用されないのではないのでしょうか？

書き込みが発行した時に 2次キャッシュに空きがなければ、 空きを作る動作が 余計に必要となるため、それが、速度低下になるのではないでしょうか？。

実際には heap メモリで確保した領域付近には heap を管理するデータが格納されており、書き込む前に参照が発生すると思いますが・・。